# Organizar tabs no pyqt4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt-4

Boa tarde pessoal!
Qual comando utilizo para "quebrar" a linha de tabs? Gostaria que aparecessem, por exemplo, 3 tabs em uma linha e 3 tabs logo abaixo dela. O esqueleto que tenho referente as tabs é:

```
    # layout tab   
    tabs = qg.QTabWidget()

    # Create tabs
    tab1    = qg.QWidget()  
    tab2    = qg.QWidget()
    tab3    = qg.QWidget()
    tab4    = qg.QWidget()
    tab5    = qg.QWidget()
    tab6    = qg.QWidget()

    tabs.addTab(tab1,"Properties")
    tabs.addTab(tab2,"Nodes")
    tabs.addTab(tab3,"Bars")
    tabs.addTab(tab4,"Restrains") 
    tabs.addTab(tab5,"Nodal Loads") 
    tabs.addTab(tab6,"Dist.Loads")
```

Comment: Não faz esta atrocidade: http://hallofshame.gp.co.at/tabs.htm

Answer (score 0):

O QT não tem esse objeto, então, você teria que fazer **manualmente**:

Crie um layout vertical, coloque um `QStackedWidget` e vários `QTabBar`s. Você vai ter que manualmente definir métodos pra garantir que só uma aba esteja selecionada em todas as `QTabBar` e mostrar o conteúdo correto no `QStackedWidget`.

Dito isso, recomendo que repense a utilização desse tipo de diálogo, que é terrível! Pensa numa janela ruim de mexer:

[image: varias abas]